# converting a binary tree into List<List<Node>>

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

IS my algorithm correct?

```
List<List<Node> > ol = new ArrayList<List<Node>>();
build(root,0)

void build (Node node,int level)
{ 
 if(node==null)
    return;
  List<Node> il;
  if(ol.size() < level){
   il =  new ArrayList<Node>(); 
  }else{
  il= ol.get(level);
  }

il.add(node);
ol.put(level,il);
 build(node.left, level+1);
 build(node.right,level+1);
}
```

Comment: In general, if you want to know if some code you wrote is correct, write a test!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a list of nodes for each level, this seems to be correct, except:

1. `ol.put(level,il);` List doesn't have a put method (it would be `set` in that case).
2. I'd drop the line above and add a `ol.add(il)` after creating the new array list for the level.
3. I'd also pass the outer list as a method parameter instead of using a member variable (although that's more of a design issue)
4. There's a `;` missing after `build(root, 0)`

Edit: to clarify no. 2:

```
if(ol.size() < level) {
  il = new ArrayList<Node>();
  ol.add(il); //add here only, assuming level = ol.size() + 1 always is true in this case
}
```

Comment: No, provided that level = size + 1, `add(il)` would be sufficient. `add(index, il)` would right shift the entries (which would break the order) and would not work for index > size.

Comment: There is no need to right shiff.We need to add a element in list i

Comment: @dojo Exactly, that's why you shouldn't use `add(index, il)`, or better `add(size(),il)` is the same as `add(il)` if index == size() (which is the only way that would not break your logic) . :)

Comment: add(il) will add elemet to end , we should replace the entry(list) at index i and not add ad end of outer list.

Comment: @dojo 1. For replacing you'd need `set(...)`. 2. This only works if the element is already initialized. If index is >= size this would not work. From the JavaDoc on `set()`: `IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the specified index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size()).`